# Using Scrapy to fill text area for logging in

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the player info from Transfer Market(https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop), and I successfully got the data I want.

But when I tried to scrape "My Player Watchlist"(https://www.transfermarkt.com/darrellcity/spielerWatchlist/meintm/1019535) from the website, which requires logging in, I had no idea how to fill in the text fields using Scrapy.
I tried with Scrapy.FormRequests, but found that the website doesn't use the POST method to log in. Also, I tried to use selenium to finish logging in before scraping with Scrapy, but it seemed not working.

I know how to do it in Selenium, but I want to use Scrapy instead to increase the speed of scraping and updating data.

Below is my code for the player list that doesn't requires logging in

````
import time
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class TMSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapyfirst'
    allowed_domain = ["transfermarkt.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [f"https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?page={i}" for i in range(1,11)]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self,response):
        item = ProjItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//td/a[not(contains(text(),"\r\n"))]/text()').getall()
        item['value'] = response.xpath('//td/a[not(contains(text(),"\r\n"))]/text()').getall()
        yield item```
````

Comment: I took a look at the website and seems like it does use a POST-request to login (as you can see if you open the Network tab in Chrome when logging in).

Comment: Thanks! After checking it again I found the Form Data in the xhr file for Scrapy form requests